# Set asp:HiddenField value on anchor click in jQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I have a HiddenField and two anchors:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfForm" runat="server" />

<a href="javascript:;" id="signup" onclick="signupClick()">Sign Up</a>
<a href="javascript:;" id="login" onclick="loginClick()">Login</a>
```

I'm trying to set the value of clicked anchor to the hidden field as like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {            
    $("a").click(function() {
        $("<%= hfForm.ClientID %>").val($(this).val());
    });
});
```

But it's getting empty in page_load on postback:

```
if (this.IsPostBack)
{
    string val = hfForm.Value; // getting "" val
}
```

How I can solve this?

### Updated

JavaScript functions (where I'm setting a value to the asp:Label value):

```
function loginClick() {
  document.getElementById('<%=lbl.ClientID%>').innerText = 'Login';
}
function signupClick() {
  document.getElementById('<%=lbl.ClientID%>').innerText = 'SignUp';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's an anchor you should use `$(this).text()` rather than `.val()` inside the `click` event, you can use `.val()` on elements that have a value attribute, change your

```
 $("<%= hfForm.ClientID %>").val($(this).val());
```

to

```
 $("<%= hfForm.ClientID %>").val($(this).text());
```

**EDIT**

You have `signUp()` and `signOut()` on the same anchors where are those functions and what do they do ? and why are you not utilizing those funtions to assign the value to the hidden field.

and you are using `href` value as `href="javascript:;"` instead it should be `href="javascript:void(0);"` or you can add the `e.preventDefault()` inside your click event.

Your function will look like below

```
$(document).ready(function() {            
    $("a").on('click',function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("<%= hfForm.ClientID %>").val($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Comment: its again getting "" value in page_load .

Comment: does adding `console.log($("<%= hfForm.ClientID %>").length)` return you `1` or `0` when you add it inside `$("a").click(function() {` and click the anchor? i am not an `asp` guy thou bu i think the problem is on `js` side.